# What's the difference between "Replica-Pairs" and "Master-Master" replication in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Given that MongoDB describes [Replica-Pairs replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Pairs) as

> ...databases automatically coordinate
>   which is the master and which is the
>   slave at a given point in time.
>
> At startup, the databases will
>   negotiate which is master and which is
>   slave. Upon an outage of one database
>   server, the other will automatically
>   take over and become master from that
>   point on.

how is this different from Master-Master replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With replica pairs, only one database is master at a time, so only one database can be written to at a time. The second database will always be a slave, available for failover,

With master-master replication, which is discouraged with MongoDB, both nodes can be written to.

Comment: With replica pairs, is it possible to add more than one "slave?" Let's say I needed a handful of slaves for read purposes, is it better to run a master with the slaves and do the failover manually in the event the master goes down?

Comment: It will be once replica sets are implemented (http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-557). In the meantime, the solution you suggest works fine.